# Object visible only from the bottom

Tags: unity

When I place my fbx file in unity it's only visible from the bottom, when I look at it from the top I can't see anything. How can I fix that?

This is how it looks in blender: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRjng.jpg

This is how it looks from the bottom in Unity: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWjsL.jpg

This is how it looks from the top in Unity: https://i.stack.imgur.com/juktp.jpg

Comment: Include screenshots inline into the question body please; [see how](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post); if link for the screenshot goes down (e.g. you remove images from Imgur) this question won't be quite clear any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, the normals are facing the wrong direction. Unity doesn't render the backside of polygons, while blender does.

Try flipping the normals around. [The reference for doing this is here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/normals.html#flip-direction).

Comment: To spot problems like this early you can enable backface culling in the 'N' panel (toggle open with N key). Then your mesh will display similarly to game engines. To make your mesh visible from both sides, you can also try the solidify modifier.

Comment: Please include some details in the answer itself on how to flip normals, just in case that manual link is unavailable at some point.